# access viewchild of 'A' in 'B' component

Tags: angular

Trying to access methods in Class UploadModal, method get called but getting error for  **_file**

```
export class UploadModal {
   @ViewChild(NgFileSelect) _file: NgFileSelect;

  // this method is called
  calledMethod(event, fileType) { 

  const name: string = this._file.uploader._queue[0].name; // getting this._file undefined

}

export class ImageComponent {   // other class in which I need to only use methods in class UploadModal
    callingMethod($event, fileType) {
        let uploadModal = new UploadModal();
        uploadModal.calledMethod($event, fileType);
    }
}
```

Comment: show the html and child component

Comment: Hi Sachila just updated code, please review.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the child via `ViewChild` in the lifecycle hook called `ngAfterViewInit`. In this cycle your view is ready and it can get a child.

From the [**Documentation**](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild)

> View queries are set before the ngAfterViewInit callback is called.

```
@Component({selector: 'someCmp', templateUrl: 'someCmp.html'})
class SomeCmp implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild(ChildDirective) child: ChildDirective;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // child is set
  }
}
```

Comment: Im not initializing component, only need to access methods of this component, is there any alternative?

Comment: No. The child will be available only when the view is ready. View is ready at the `ngAfterViewInit`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet

```
export class ImageComponent {   
    componentRef: UploadModal;
    constructor(){ this.componentRef = new UploadModal(); }
    callingMethod($event, fileType) {
        this.componentRef.calledMethod($event, fileType);
    }
}
```